# Create Zip File with multiple users

Tags: c#, zip, multi-user

I would like to create a Zip File on my Computer under my account.
My user can't access the filesystem and the Filesystemaccount cant access my computer. I tried to solve this Problem withe a wraper to use the other account to get a list of the files but when i want to create the ZIP File i cant access the data.  What would be a solution for this problem. As Info i have used the Ionic Zip Framework, because i wanted to split the Zip File.

Comment: You can make the folder on your PC shared and then give access to other users/groups.  Then the folder would look like a shared drive \\mypc\sharedfolder\abc.zip

Comment: As Workaround a i have used my wraper to copy the files to the Tmp Folder and create then the Zip File.